# Detecting selection change in datasheet form in Access

Tags: ms-access, events, selection, datasheet

Is there event in Access that detects change of column selection on the same row in datasheet view?

Answer (score 0):

Not in pure datasheet view, but you can create a form and apply datasheet view. And then, all controls bounded to the table got the property `TextBox.OnLostFocus`. Read more about it:

> [**TextBox.OnLostFocus Property
>   (Access)**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-onlostfocus-property-access)

There, you can play and design code to detect when user changes column.